# Writing a tag wiki for sports

Tags: discussion, tags

I just tried to write up a tag wiki for sports
I can't wrap my head around the term, it is sooo endlessly broad. I have no idea if it is even a good tag…
Every physical activity is a sport, and even non physical activities are sports.

I try to create tag wikis without consulting Wikipedia, but as I wasn't able to come up with a definition myself, I checked their article on [Sport](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sport#Meaning_and_usage).

> Sport (or sports) is all forms of usually competitive physical activity which, through casual or organised participation, aim to use, maintain or improve physical ability and skills while providing entertainment to participants, and in some cases, spectators. Hundreds of sports exist, from those requiring only two participants, through to those with hundreds of simultaneous participants, either in teams or competing as individuals. Sport is generally recognised as activities which are based in physical athleticism or physical dexterity, with the largest major competitions such as […]
>
> There are opposing views on the necessity of competition as a defining element of a sport […] For instance, the Council of Europe include all forms of physical exercise, including those completed just for fun.

While it is pretty clear that on our site only questions about the physical activities known as sport are on topic. But every question on this site is about physical activities, after all.

This tag seems a bit redundant, as every question could be tagged with it. I am not sure if it possible to narrow down the scope of this tag.

Ideas welcome!

Comment: Just looking at some of the [tag:sports] questions, I would probably use other tags that relate more to the subject than just "sports" in general. Honestly, it might be better to retag those questions and use more specific terms like what [Sports Stack Exchange](http://sports.stackexchange.com/tags) has.